# Find IDs from another table using wildcards

Tags: sql

I need to find all IDs from second table that correspond to values from first table row (`publications`).

Tables are like this:

```
Customers:                           Publications:
ID   name         publications       ID    pub_short
------------------------------       ---------------
1    ABC Motors   2                  1     AA
2    Ecco         1|3|2              2     BB
3    Third        3|2|4              3     CC
4    Fourth       2|4                4     DD
5    Fifth        3|4                5     EE
...                                  ...
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.*
FROM Customers
WHERE '%'+publications+'%' IN 
  (SELECT ID FROM Publications WHERE pub_short LIKE 'b%')
ORDER BY `Customers`.`name` ASC
```

and it gives me IDs `1` and `4` (BB), but not `2` and `3`.

Is there a wildcard to use in that situation, or some other approach?

Comment: Bad design leads to complicated queries. Read about RDBMS design

Comment: rather have an extra table called `customer_publications` that will link those tables together

Comment: What would be a better design, provided I need to add new 'pub_shorts' to 'Publications' and new 'publications' to 'Customers'?

Comment: See here for a better design and the corresponding query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63675/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT c.*
FROM Customers c
join Publications p
ON INSTR(c.publications, p.ID) > 0
WHERE p.pub_short LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY `c`.`name` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

```
select c.*
  from customers c,
       publications p
 where p.pub_short like 'B%'
   and publications like '%'||p.id||'%';
```

Please note that I tested this on Oracle SQL and it's case sensitive hence the 'b%' line of yours has been changed to 'B%'. 
No big deal, could be solved with an UPPER p.pub_short.